# Solr Query Not Working With Emojis

Tags: solr

So I have a solr index that has a column called text. One of the entries has a text value of "Euro: €€€€". When I do a search with q=euro, I get the entry to pop up as expected. However, when I do a search for any number of the euro symbol, e.g. q=€€€, nothing turns up.

According to the Solr documentation it should work for any utf-8 characters. What gives?

I'm happy to provide more information about my solr setup if necessary.

Comment: Which kind of type is the `text` column?

Comment: @freedev text_en_splitting